# Lost synced contacts in my HTC Desire HD

Tags: contacts, sync, htc-desire-hd

I have synced my contacts with my Google account in my HTC Desire HD. It showed that over 400 contacts synced successfully. But I was not using that Google account as activ. Than I have installed a custom rom to my HTC and added my Google account but my contacts are lost. Where should be those contacts? Where did it synced? Do you have any idea?

Update:

The rom I have installed is CyanogenMod and I have enabled sync and contacts to display is set to all. The problem is I can't see my contacts in gmail. Before I install new rom I have confirmed in contacts application of HTC that all my contacts synced with my Google account.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-enable syncing of your Google contacts. Here's a simple guide on how to do that: http://www.wikihow.com/Sync-Google-Contacts-With-Android.

Also, the contacts may be on your phone, but not set to display. To fix this, go into your contacts list, hit the menu/options button, and open "Contacts to Display". Make sure that your gmail contact list is enabled in this menu.

Finally, if those don't work, check this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/zCWHBp5d9h4